# Why can I echo an environment variable but not use it to cd or ls?

Tags: bash, variables, env

How come I can `echo` the `$RUBYPATH` variable:

```
[grant@rails-box app]$ echo $RUBYPATH
/opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0
```

And `ls` that directory:

```
[grant@rails-box app]$ ls /opt/rubies/ruby-2.3.0
bin  include  lib  share
```

But I can't `ls` using the variable?

```
[grant@rails-box app]$ ls $RUBYPATH
: No such file or directoryes/ruby-2.3.0
```

Comment: Given that the error message appears garbled, the variable may have embedded unprintable characters: `echo $RUBYPATH | cat -vet`

Comment: Specifically, the value of `RUBYPATH` ends with a carriage return. You need to fix this where `RUBYPATH` is set. Likely, you are reading from a file that uses DOS line endings.

Comment: And extending the advice, run `dos2unix` on your ~/.bashrc (or whatever file declares that variable).

Comment: Absolutely right. I had ^M line endings in there... Thanks windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Bishop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2908724/bishop) is right: try

```
$ echo $RUBYPATH | cat -v # or hexdump -C
```